# Laravel access values from object in object

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent, model

In one of the controller function

```
$readings = Reading::orderBy('reading_date_time', 'DESC')->get();
dd($readings);
```

This gives

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1883
  #items: array:160 [
    0 => App\Reading {#1722
      #fillable: array:6 [ …6]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "readings"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [ …8]
      #original: array:8 [ …8]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
    }...
```

How can I access the actual values of readings table. And use them for operations like array_column().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213847/how-to-get-access-the-values-of-object-which-are-starting-from-in-laravel-php

you can check this one if want to access the values of # staring variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function already give you the result, and the result is [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections).

You can call the attribute by single object in collection:

```php
$readings->first()->reading_date_time;
```

and you can use [method-pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) to get the attribute values from collection, it just like `array_column`:

```php
$readings->pluck('reading_date_time');
```

If you use `array_column`, you can use [method-toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray) to change collection to array:

```php
array_column($readings->toArray(), 'reading_date_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `toArray()` helper

> The toArray method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If
>   the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be
>   converted to arrays

```
$readings = Reading::orderBy('reading_date_time', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();

/*
    [
        ['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', ...],
        ['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', ...],
        ['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', ...],
        ...
    ]
*/
```

Then you may use `array_column()` on `$readings` **array**

```
$pluckedValues = array_column($readings, 'chosen_column');

print_r($pluckedValues);
```