# How to get access the values of object which are starting from # in laravel dd(); php?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, object, laravel-5

I used this ***"mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"*** pkg of laravel for device detection and want to print the **userAgent** value.I call this method

```
$this->device = new MobileDetect();
dd($this->device)
```

After that i got this result:
[image]

now i want to print userAgent value.
I have tried these code but not working.

```
dd($this->device->userAgent,$this->device["userAgent"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also facing this issue a few days ago.
I have a solution for it you can try.

```
$this->device->getUserAgent();
```

I was facing the same issue for access the ***#fillable*** values in the Model

```
dd(User::get()[0]->getFillable(),User::get()[0]);
```

[image]